# What is the name of Pogba's body swerve played on Mustafi?

Tags: football, terminology, euro

On 7 July 2016 during the match [Germany-France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFA_Euro_2016_knockout_phase#Germany_vs_France) for Euro 2016 at minute 72 Pogba has disoriented the defender Mustafi with a body move.

> I would like to know if this movement has a particular name?

I will add the link to a video as soon as I find it.

The goal be seen on [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UayIQoI9eHg&feature=youtu.be&t=107) from official UEFA youtube channel.

Comment: As far as I can say videos with goals and highlights online are often deleted by the copyright holder. So even if you add video, it might not be available for too long, unless it comes from some official source. But I guess that some videos could be found by searching for 
[Pogba 2nd goal](https://www.google.com/search?q=pogba+2nd+goal&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A7%2F7%2F2016%2Ccd_max%3A7%2F8%2F2016&tbm=vid) or 
[France Germany 2nd goal](https://www.google.com/search?q=France+Germany+2nd+goal&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A7%2F7%2F2016%2Ccd_max%3A7%2F8%2F2016&tbm=vid). (I have also restricted the dates.)

Comment: Here is [discussion of the 2nd goal on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/soccer/comments/4rqqyq/griezmann_scores_vs_germany_20/). It has some video, although Pogba's move is not easy to see from this angle and distance.

Comment: And perhaps it will be possible to find also some animated gifs or [vines](https://vine.co/tags/pogba).

Comment: Link sends to video of WTA October Shots of the Month?

Comment: @leDominatre My mistake. I must have copied the url from the wrong tab.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'll go with the [Flip flap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip_flap_(association_football)) on this one.

It was, however, a weird variation. The *flip* part wasn't that explicit :) (Pogba played more with the intention). I'd say Mustafi naiveness helped a bit there.

This video of the play has been online for a while:
https://youtu.be/FtuJJV7MyPg

Another one with some crazy variations has been online for a longer time:
https://youtu.be/2TSX9L4Ayl8